# Firebase get all keys or values from reference?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Just an example of what im looking for is i have a list of keys/values in my realtime database at a location ive already referenced is it possible for me to get all keys or all values at that from that referenced location?

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you subscribe to its `view` event and you'll asynchronously get the contents:

```
ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

Comment: ref would refer to my database reference but i dont see a once method?(this is on android)

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed that. You probably want "addListenerForSingleValueEvent ", specified here: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/database/Query#public-methods

Comment: Ok now how can I get the list from the datasnapshot?